# What's the best way to diff files among remote servers?

Tags: linux, command-line, diff

Is there any command or utils can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh + diff:

http://www.genlinux.org/2009/04/remote-diff-in-linux.html

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/compare-folder-files-from-remote-server-605143/

vim diff + scp:

http://linux.spiney.org/remote_diff_with_vim_and_ssh